# Postgresql 9.2.1 failed to initialize after full vacuum in standalone backend mode

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, vacuum

In postgresql version 9.2.1, the database didn't accept any commands to avoid wraparouond dataloss.The following error occured in the pg_log,

> **ERROR**:  database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database "XXX"
>   **HINT**:  Stop the postmaster and use a standalone backend to vacuum that database.
>       You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions.

I executed vacuum full for the database XXX in standalone backend mode.After that i tried to restart the pgsql, now pgsql server is rejecting connnections. while executing the **pg_isready** command, the host is rejecting connections.

Is there anything i have to do after completing the vacuum process? what are the possible reasons for the postgres server is failed to start ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you vacuum full every database? You might have to do the template0 and 1 dbs as well as all the others.

Comment: Also you should really upgrade to the latest 9.2. You're missing years and years of bug fixes not to mention 9.2 is no longer supported.

Comment: Why i have to vacuum every database ? The error itself mentioned the specific database where the wraparound issue is occuring @ScottMarlowe.

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade advice. I will have it as my last card. @ScottMarlowe

Comment: Once you have fixed the wraparound problem, you should **at least** upgrade to the latest 9.2 version which is 9.2.23

Comment: Ya sure. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 0):

In single user mode, run

```
SELECT datname, datfrozenxid FROM pg_database;
```

to see which databases need to be vacuumed (those with the smallest values).

Run `VACUUM (FREEZE)` in these databases, *not* `VACUUM (FULL)`.

Comment: There is no **datminmxid** attribute in pg_database for the version 9.2.1. And i have to vacuum (freeze) the one with smallest **datfrozenxid**, right ?

Comment: Right. And upgrading to a later PostgreSQL won't help. You must get that `VACUUM (FREEZE)` done *now*; upgrade later.

Comment: Thanks. do vacuum freeze or full cause any problems to the data in the database ? Data remains intact, right ?

Comment: `VACUUM` won't destroy data. You need `VACUUM (FREEZE)` against transaction ID wraparound; `VACUUM (FULL)` won't help. You data will only be destroyed if you *don't* run `VACUUM (FREEZE)`.

Comment: In case, if the vacuum freeze process also get failed. Is there any way other than upgrading the postgresql version ?

Comment: Upgrading won't help. You have to run `VACUUM (FREEZE)`. There is no alternative.

Comment: While opening in single user mode, it just froze with message,   **Warning: Database with OID XXXX must be vacuumed within 1000000 transactions. Hint:To avoid a database shutdown, execute a database-wide vacuum in the database. You might also need to commit or rollback old prepared transaction.** I couldn't proceed the vacuum freeze step.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't "just freeze". Did you use `--single` as first argument when starting? Did you try to enter `VACUUM`? If you can't get it to work, get professional support. You're running the risk of losing your data.

Comment: i used  (**postgres.exe --single -D "./../data" <DB_NAME>**) command to enter into the single user mode from the location **pgsql/bin**

Comment: It's working. Actually, it was my mistake. After entering the single user mode command, it took sometime to enter into single user mode. Now my **vacuum freeze** process is running. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I'll keep my fingers crossed that everything works well for you!